# Is there a viable synonym for the verb "nod"?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

Reading through my manuscript, I realize I have overused the verb "nod" - as in *"This sounds great", she agreed nodding.*

It seems to me there is a slight problem in that there aren't any great, viable synonyms for a gesture that is very common in human conversation.

Or am I wrong? Is there any alternative to overusing this expression?

To clarify, I'm looking for a verb indicating the **gesture** (i.e. the motion of the head), not the meaning of agreement (such as e.g. *"This sounds great", she concurred*)

Comment: [smh](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smh)

Comment: So, you give the direct speech in which agreement happens, you say she agreed... perhaps you don't always need to add a gesture of agreement as well?

Comment: Yeah, even without throwing in any other new terms, permuting agreement, tone, and gestures can mix it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bobbing** one's head — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bob)

> 1. Make a quick, short movement up and down
>
> *"I could see his head bobbing about"*
> *"Unlike Garrett's bewildered reaction, Clara only gave a slight bob of her head to acknowledge him."*
>
> <sub>*Synonyms: nod, incline, bow, dip, duck*</sub>

Comment: Good idea. I still think it's a crime we have 10 different words to describe a buzzing sound but only a couple for this gesture. But hey, at least now there's 2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Bowed her head, winked assent, dipped her head, touched her hat, gave a thumbs up, angled her chin down, or tilted her head. It's hard to say "nod" without saying "nod," but there are physical cues that are roughly equivalent, at least in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many sites on body language [(this one called Entrepreneur)](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/245046) suggests, for **assent**:

> Start with the eyes, making solid contact, then nod in assent and
>   **raise your eyebrows** while you listen. You’ll look **alert** and
>   interested. A **perked** head position, nodding in agreement. A head **tilt**
>   to the side is a submissive signal, exposing the throat and neck; it
>   conveys inquisitiveness and interest.

Alternatives but not really synonyms (emphasis added)